# How do I change the Company Name & URL in the "App Info" Page (iPhone App)?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect

In my App, there is a page that says "App Info", with the sections "Ratings", "Tell a Friend", "App Support", "Company Name", "Updated", "Version", "Size", "Rating", and "Legal"

In the "Company Name" Section, it lists my name and no URL. How do I change the name and URL that is listed?

Answer (score 2):

If your company actually changed its name, you may be able to change the name on your developer account (which is the name that's displayed in iTunes). Call [Apple Worldwide Developer Support](https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone.php).

You should be able to edit all the other information (support URL, etc.) in iTunesConnect when you submit an update to your app.

Answer (score 1):

The Company name is set when you registered for the iOS Developer Program. As far as I'm aware there is no way to change this, you were prompted for it during registration and the help text explicitly mentions that you can't change it later. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You could always show your company URL as the App's support URL

iTunesConnect -> Manage Your Applications -> select App

click Edit at 'App Localizations' and change fill out support URL field

Comment: SO just asked me if i'm a human being when i was posting this answer... hmm :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite the same thing, but you can change the 'copyright name' when updating your app (in addition to the support and marketing URLs). However, it doesn't look quite as good as using a company name; in order to change *that* you'll need to contact Apple via iTunes Connect and give them details of your company.